# Geocoding google maps wrong location

Tags: google-maps

i'm trying to put an marker in the position ( -23.426056, -47.599556 ) in the Simple Map Example (http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html) and the marker never stay in the right place. In Google Maps I always get two markers, a red one(that marks the street) and the green one(an arrow that marks the right th exact place) like in this photo http://s4.postimg.org/6ahyt0rm5/ibagen.gif

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where the marker belongs (the coordinates), don't use the geocoder, just put the marker where you want it. Like [this example from the Google Maps API v3 documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)
Note that the example in you post is using the Google Maps API v2, whih was deprecated May 19, 2010; and reaches end of life May 19, 2013.  New development using that version is discouraged.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Simple</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.426056, -47.599556);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```